# Full screen menu divi transparant background to color background on click

Tags: css, menu, header, transparent, divi

I have a question about my full screen menu.
I want it transparent when just scrolling and using the page. But when I click on the hamburger icon in the right top the full screen menu opens. The problem is that I can't fix the background to get a black color when it opens. It stays transparent. Can someone please help me to get the background of the menu black on click?

This is the code I use in the header

Menu Toggle animation

```
<html>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <span class="label">Click for animation.</span>
  <div id="smallWrapper">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div id="bars">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>

<style>
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 3em);
  left: calc(50% - 2em);
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #CCC;
}

#smallWrapper {
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 20px);
  left:calc(50% - 20px);
}

input {
  opacity:0;
  z-index:1;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  appearance: none;
}

#bars {
  width:40px;
  height:35.3333333333333333px;
  padding-top: 4.6666666666666666666px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s,  transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.bar {
  width 40px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 9.3333333333333333px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.5s linear;

}

input:checked + #bars {
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 20%, 0.0);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

input:checked + #bars .bar {
  background:#fff;
}

input:checked + #bars .bar:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px, 9.33333333333333333px);
}

input:checked + #bars .bar:nth-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input:checked + #bars .bar:last-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -9.33333333333333333px);
}
</style>
```

Menu transform to full screen animation:

```
<script>jQuery(function($){
$('#menu-open').click(function() {
$('.section-transform').toggleClass('section-transform-active');
});
$('.menu-item-click').click(function() {
$('.section-transform').removeClass('section-transform-active');
});
});</script>

<style>
section-transform{
cursor: pointer;    
}
.section-transform-active {
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
z-index: 99999 !important;
background-color: #000000 !important; 
}   
.section-transform {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}
</style>
```

JS that belongs to above css:

```
<script>
$('#hamburger').click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
</script>
```

I Hope someone can help me out.
The URL of the site is [www.nr-design.nl](http://www.nr-design.nl)

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

hey use onClick function to make your background black when you click on it

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. But it's not as simple as that. I use a toggle (hamburger icon) to open the menu. So when i click the toggle the background should change from transparant to black.

Comment: so to change it onclick function can be used